# Is the surface of Venus red hot?

Tags: venus, planet, surface, heat

I was wondering, is the surface of Venus so hot that it would glow red in the dark (e.g. on the dark side of Venus)?  I am working on making a solar system simulator, and that would make for a great level if it is accurate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The average surface temperature on Venus is 462 °C. You would need a temperature above 800 °C before you would notice any light.

Added:
Here are some calculated radiation outputs of the surface [temperature of Venus](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B80IPeLPxBV3WnFCWWF6RTNuV28/edit?usp=sharing), [a 1000 °C black body](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B80IPeLPxBV3a094ZkxveTdqdG8/edit?usp=sharing) and [the sun](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B80IPeLPxBV3VTk0UU5mZjc5dkk/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: I found this reference that shows it can be seen as low as 500 °C, which is still above (but very close to) your stated average of 462 °C on Venus.  Therefore at least on average, the surface probably still would not glow.  However, I wonder if there are still parts of Venus that would be this hot (e.g. possibly the equator)? http://hypertextbook.com/facts/2000/StephanieLum.shtml

Comment: Old question I realize, but Venus' equator and Venus' north and south poles are the same temperature.   The planet traps heat efficiently enough that the temperature is consistent at any latitude and any season.